# Updating Gmail profile photo privacy after sending message, who can see it?

Tags: gmail, profile-picture

When I send an email using Gmail it has a profile pic and is visible to everyone. After sending a message, I changed my picture and set it to "not visible to contacts."

Will the recipient of the Gmail get to still see my picture or will it change to where they cannot see it any more?

Answer (score 3):

This link would give you all the details you need: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=35529

You can choose to set your profile picture to be displayed either to your Google chat contacts only or to be seen by everyone. If you choose the former one, the email you sent out will not have your picture. This is provided you changed your settings before you sent the mail. Once the recipient checks for new mail, he/she basically pulls content from the mail server (similar even in the case of push notifications) and you wouldn't have control over the copy of the email.